# Find out if someone has a role

Tags: javascript, node.js, roles, discord.js

I made a simple quote bot for a server, but the admin only wants mod+ people to be able to add quotes to avoid spam. I went to the documentation and did everything, but I can't get this to work. Here's what I have:

```
//other code
else if (command === "addquote" && arg) {
    let adminRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Admin");
    let modRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Mod");

    if(message.member.roles.has(adminRole) || message.member.roles.has(modRole)){
        const hasArr = arr.some((el) => {
            return el.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '') === arg.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
        });

        if(hasArr){
            message.channel.send(arg.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim() + " is already a Quote");
        } else {
            fs.appendFileSync('./Quotes.txt', '\r\n' + arg);
            message.channel.send("Quote added: " + arg);
            arr.push(arg);            
        }   
    }
}
```

It's very finicky. Sometimes it will work if the user has the mod role, most of the times it wont. If I do

```
console.log(message.memeber.roles.has(adminRole));
console.log(message.memeber.roles.has(modRole));
```

both will output to false, but will work?
Honestly, I have no idea at this point.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The discord.js api has been updated and there is a better way since `.exists()` has been deprecated.

`if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Whatever')) {}`

This is better than `.find()` because `.find()` returns the role object (or undefined) which is then converted into a boolean. The `.some()` method returns a boolean by default.

Comment: @JackNicholson `if (!message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Whatever'))` seems like it would work for that.

Answer (score 22):

`message.member.roles` is a collection. Instead of getting the roles object, then looking for it, just look for the role directly in the collection. Try this:

```
else if (command === "addquote" && arg) {
    if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Admin") || message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Mod")){
        // The rest of your code.
    }
```

**Note**, the role name must be the name you put in the find method, including any emojis if there's any in the role name.

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me with version 12.2.0

```
if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Admin")) {
    // Your code
}
```

You can also use `r.id` to check with the role id

Comment: This is the up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 10):

The [Map.has](http://www.collectionsjs.com/method/has-key) method checks for keys, not values, so you'll have to use the roles' ids instead.

`message.member.roles.has(adminRole.id)`

`message.member.roles.has(modRole.id)`

Comment: Ahh, thank you, but when I made the correction and added the .id part I got an error that said "Can't find property of null" when doing the if statement

Answer (score 5):

**Discord.js Version: v12 (stable).**

If you have the `role ID`, you can check if the `.roles` Collection on a GuildMember object includes it, using `.has()`. Should you not know the ID and want to check for something like a "Mod" role, you can use `.some()`.

```
member.roles.cache.has('role-id-here');
// returns true if the member has the role

member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Admin');
// returns true if any of the member's roles is exactly named "Admin"
```

***Example IF;***

```
const roleById = member.roles.cache.has('123456...');
//or if you want in message
const rolebyIdMessage = message.member.roles.cache.has('12346....');

if(member.roles.cache.has(roleById) return message.reply("Member With Role!");
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm probably wayy to late with this, but I just had the same problem, and the way i solved it is to search for the role, and then check if the variable has anything on it.
Say i wanna check for if the author of the message has admin role:

```
client.on('message',message =>{

     adminrole = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Admin");
     if(adminrole != null){memberIsAdmin = true;}else{memberIsAdmin = false;}

}
```

Maybe this will help someone, note that I'm not very experienced with js tho :)
Have a nice day y'all

Answer (score 2):

`if(message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "VIP"))`

Comment: This will return the role from the server, but does not verify if it has been applied to a user.

Answer (score 2):

That wouldn't work in the newest version of Discord.js which is v12. You need to add `if(message.guild.roles.cache.find(roles => role.name === 'VIP'))`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be traditional or approved, but I've been stuck on this question for a while and the solution in the accepted answer always returned true for me. Anyway, what worked for me was:

```
message.mentions.members.first()._roles.includes(role.id)
```

This returns true and false correctly.