# Discord.js - Check if command author have a role / Allow command for a specified role

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord.js bot and I have a command...

I want the command to be for the "VIP" role only, so how to check the message author's role?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317305/find-out-if-someone-has-role-discord-js

Comment: @Whatever - I saw that but this is not for the command author (message author).

Comment: What is a command if not a message? You first parse a message, you see it's a command, you check role, you either execute command or reply "VIP only".

Comment: Yes, and I want to know how to check role. @Whatever

Comment: in `message.member.roles.find("name", "Admin")` what is this "name"?

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role and
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection

Answer (score 0):

This is the working answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45318432/8524395

I understood that "name" shouldn't be changed (it should specifically be "name").

So:

```
if(message.member.roles.find("name", "VIP")){
  // Rest of your code
}else{
  // not vip
}
```

And "name" shouldn't be changed. :)