# Checking predefined role and executing a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need to check if a user has a predefined role, and if it has the role, remove it. If it does not, then send a message saying something.

```
let user = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(x => x.name === "Muted");

if (user.roles.has(muterole)) user.removeRole(muterole);
if (!user.roles.has(muterole)) message.channel.send("This user does not have the muted role!");
```

I expected it to remove the role if the `user` had it, and to send a message if he did not.
However my current results are it sends the message no matter if he has the `Muted` role, and if he does have it, it does not remove it.

My end goal is this. My `mute` command uses `node ms` so I can mute for a specified time, so I need an unmute, but if the user is unmuted, that does not stop the timer (I don't think there is a way) so my idea was to put in the mute command -> "If user has `mute` after time remove the role, but if the user does not have the `mute` role, return"

Comment: `user.roles` seems to be an array.  I know of no standard `arr.has` method, did you mean to use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Someone told me it was `member.roles.has(mutedRole.id)` but I was unsure on how to adapt that to read the user from `let user =` and the role from `let muterole =`

Comment: I think you’re right about using the id.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317305/find-out-if-someone-has-a-role)

Answer (score 0):

this might work to detect if the member has the role

```js
// assuming role.id is an actual ID of a valid role:
if(message.member.roles.has(role.id)) {
  console.log(`Yay, the author of the message has the role!`);
} else {
  console.log(`author does not have the role`);
}
```

Comment: I am unsure if this works, I can't seem to make it work, can you maybe try and adapting it to fit into here? https://hastebin.com/ehinatabij.js
Basically, if the user has the role, run that, if not, cancel. Because if someone manually unmutes, the unmute embed and attempt will run anyway at the moment.