# Trying to create a warning system for my discord.js bot. What have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a bot for a client, and I'm making a warning system that can be triggered by `(prefix) warn <user mention>`. I have the code below.

I can run the command once, and it will add the Warning 1 role, but subsequent commands don't add warnings 2 or 3.

```js
if (mentionedUser.roles.cache.has(warn1)){
    if (mentionedUser.roles.cache.has(warn2)){
        message.channel.send('Already has 2 warnings.');
        mentionedUser.addRole(warn3);
    }
    else{
        message.channel.send('Already has 1 warning.')
        mentionedUser.addRole(warn2);
    }
}
else{
    mentionedUser.roles.add(warn1);
    message.channel.send('Warned the user.');
}
```

Comment: Looks like "mentionedUser.roles.cache.has(warn1)" is always false.
Are you sure it's the good verification ? I dont know discord but why the role would be in cache ?

Comment: You could check these exemples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317305/find-out-if-someone-has-a-role if it helps

Comment: @Leyffda discord.js v12 uses cache. in v11 it would have been `mentionedUser.roles.has(warn1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing v11 and v12 syntax. You add `warn1` using `roles.add` (v12) but add `warn2` using `user.addRole` (v11). If `warn1` works, you're using discord.js v12, so you should use `mentionedUser.roles.add` everywhere:

```js
// role IDs
const warn1 = '808376848172974143';
const warn2 = '808376936006418524';
const warn3 = '808377003580457000';
const mute = '808377222884753459';
const beenMuted = '810008640802258975';
const mentionedUser = message.mentions.members.first();

if (mentionedUser.roles.cache.has(warn1)) {
    if (mentionedUser.roles.cache.has(warn2)) {
        message.channel.send('Already has 2 warnings.');
        mentionedUser.roles.add(warn3);
    }
    else {
        message.channel.send('Already has 1 warning.')
        mentionedUser.roles.add(warn2);
    }
}
else {
    mentionedUser.roles.add(warn1);
    message.channel.send('Warned the user.');
}
```

With the code above the roles are added correctly:

[image]

Comment: I tried this option, and it didn't work for me. [here's the full thing if you want to check it out](https://pastebin.com/urxykWgT). please point out where I went wrong.

Comment: @AndenWieseler Can you show me how you define the role variables? `warn1`, `warn2`, etc.

Comment: `const warn1 = message.guild.roles.cache.get('808376848172974143')
const warn2 = message.guild.roles.cache.get('808376936006418524');
const warn3 = message.guild.roles.cache.get('808377003580457000');
const mute = message.guild.roles.cache.get('808377222884753459');
const beenMuted = message.guild.roles.cache.get('810008640802258975');`

Comment: Oh, I see, all you need is the ID of the role, so you need to use them like `const warn1 = '808376848172974143'`, etc. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AndenWieseler Did it work with the role IDs?