# Discord.js: How can you check if a specific user has a role?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roles

I'm looking to see if you can check if you can test for a specific user having a role. Only problem is that I'm fairly new to Discord.js and everything I searched up was either outdated, was something I couldn't fully understand or only showed how to test if the author of the message has the role, which is not what I'm trying to find out. What should I change in my current coding?

```
if (message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES")) {

            const member = message.mentions.users.first();
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
            const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Awesome Role Name");

            if (memberTarget.roles.cache.has(role)) {
                message.channel.send(`${memberTarget} has the role!`);

            } else {
                message.channel.send(`${memberTarget} does not have the role!`);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find out if someone has a role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317305/find-out-if-someone-has-a-role). The first answer is outdated, but the other answers are up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is check if the `GuildMember.roles.cache` has the role. Also, the reason your code isn’t working is because you are using the role object. You need to use the role ID.

```js
if (memberTarget.roles.cache.has(role.id))
```

More related things:

Getting role by any property

```js
if (memberTarget.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === 'role-name'))
//does not need to be the name
```

Getting message author's roles

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id))
```

Comment: Could not thank you more, I really appreciate the help! I was starting to grow tired of trying to find the answer, and I cannot believe it was just because I needed to add '.id'!

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped! (Use the checkmark under the upvote/downvote button)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I ticked it immediately :)

Answer (score 0):

To check for a role you can do the code:

```js
if (member.roles.cache.has("ROLE_ID"))
```

If you wanted to check if the sender has the role you could do:

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.has("ROLE_ID")) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```

If you wanted to check if someone else has a role you could do:

```js
if (memberTarget.roles.cache.has("ROLE_ID")) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```

To get a member you could do it in many different ways, one method would be to get them by mentions:

```js
// This will get the first mention who is a member in the server
const memberTarget = message.mentions.members.first()
```

Read about guild member roles [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles)