# DiscordJS GuildMemberRoleManager doesn't have a cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to see if a user has a role with discordjs v13. I'm using typescript as well.

On multiple posts, I've seen people use this code:

```
function handleCommand(interaction: CommandInteraction) {
...
  let isAdmin = interaction.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Admin')
...
```

[This is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317305/find-out-if-someone-has-a-role)

However, I get an error:

```
  Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

22   console.log(interaction.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.name == "Admin"));
                                          ~~~~~
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `interaction.member.roles` is typed as a string array, not a GuildMemberRoleManager. Can you show how you cast your values

Comment: I had to manually cast it, and then it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Elitezen kindly pointed out, `interaction.member.roles` is a `string[]` instead of a `GuildMemberRoleManager`. I manually casted it to the correct type and it worked!

```js
  let roles = (interaction.member.roles as GuildMemberRoleManager).cache;
  let isAdmin = roles.some(
    (role) => role.name === "admin")
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than type casting I think it is better to check that the interaction is actually happening in a cached guild (because then `.member` will be typed as `GuildMember` and hence `.member.roles` is typed as `GuildMemberRoleManager`).

```
if (!interaction.inCachedGuild()) throw new Error('Not a cached guild')
const roles = interaction.member.roles.cache;
const isAdmin = roles.some(
  (role) => role.name === "admin")
);
```

Comment: I think your answer is best. But what is a cached guild? can you refer some documentation about or throw some light on it? thanks